# numpy.ndarray.tolist get list like generator instead of actual list?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I want to get generator object instead of list for numpy arrays.

```
for item in numpy.ndarray.tolist():
  item.do_something_with
```

Comment: `numpy.ndarray.tolist` is a bad expression.  `numpy.ndarray` is a function, not an array.  But ignoring that detail, this iteration might be better than `for item in arr:` because `tolist` is quite fast and iteration on a list is faster than iteration on an array.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any benefit there, since your array is already an iterable and in memory in the first place, but if you absolutely need a generator you could do:

```
arr = np.random.randn(10)
for item in (item for item in arr):
    ...
```

That said, iterating over the array directly would be be preferable:

```
for item in arr:
    ...
```

Comment: The array itself is already iterable. Why create the superfluous generator on top?

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over numpy arrays directly

```py
array = np.random.random(3,3,3) # 3d array

for a in array:
    do_something(a)  # a is a 2d array
    do_something_as_list(a.tolist())
    for a1 in a:  # iterate again
        ...  # a1 is a 1d array 
        # etc
```

You can iterate over every scaler element in an array like so

```py
for e in array.flat:
    do_something(e)  # e is a scaler
```

If you need to pass around the iterator (what you probably mean by generator), you can retrieve that with `iter(array)`.

Comment: `numpy.flatiter` object is not callable

Comment: @MustafaAydın fixed, it's a property